# not able to install npm without sudo

Tags: node.js, makefile, npm

I've installed node into a custom directory in my home folder called local per these instructions : https://gist.github.com/isaacs/579814

I've added the location to my `PATH` and it seems to work fine.  I cannot however seem to get npm to install without sudo.  From what I can tell it is trying to execute a command in `/bin` folder.

The command I am running from `~/local/npm` is `make install` and I got the latest versions of both node and npm from github.

Can anyone assist here?

```
user@localhost [~/local/npm]# make install
rm -rf \
    .building_ronn \
    html/doc \
    html/api \
    man
scripts/doc-build.sh doc/api/npm-view.md man/man3/npm-view.3
make[1]: Entering directory `/home1/extrabol/local/npm'
node cli.js install ronn --no-global
npm ERR! Error: EROFS, mkdir '/bin/node'
npm ERR!     at Error (native)
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this *entire* log,
npm ERR! including the npm and node versions, at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! System Linux 3.4.87-20140414.1.bh6.x86_64
npm ERR! command "node" "/home1/extrabol/local/npm/cli.js" "install" "ronn" "--no-global"
npm ERR! cwd /home1/extrabol/local/npm
npm ERR! node -v v0.11.14-pre
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.10
npm ERR! path /bin/node
npm ERR! code EROFS
npm ERR! errno -30
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home1/extrabol/local/npm/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

The Debug Log reports this

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'node',
1 verbose cli   '/home1/extrabol/local/npm/cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'install',
1 verbose cli   'ronn',
1 verbose cli   '--no-global' ]
2 info using npm@1.4.10
3 info using node@v0.11.14-pre
4 verbose node symlink /home1/extrabol/local/node/node
5 error Error: EROFS, mkdir '/bin/node'
5 error     at Error (native)
6 error If you need help, you may report this *entire* log,
6 error including the npm and node versions, at:
6 error     <http://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
7 error System Linux 3.4.87-20140414.1.bh6.x86_64
8 error command "node" "/home1/extrabol/local/npm/cli.js" "install" "ronn" "--no-global"
9 error cwd /home1/extrabol/local/npm
10 error node -v v0.11.14-pre
11 error npm -v 1.4.10
12 error path /bin/node
13 error code EROFS
14 error errno -30
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.  Looks like when I git cloned the npm files somehow I didn't have ownership over all of the files.  a quick `chown -R` on the npm folder fixed the issue.